# Apache apache2.conf issue

Tags: apache, yii2-advanced-app

I wantend to access two different version of my site(based on yii2 framework) via slash: http://url.com and http://url.com/something would bring me to another version.

For achieving this i took "something" directory and put it into "url" directory.

It was fine, but not exactly what i wanted, because it seemed like "something" part wasnt loading it's .css and scripts.

I went to **apache2.conf** file, and modified it -

**before:**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/bahruz/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**after:**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/bahruz/www/etap/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After i did this, https://url.com opens site without css and scripts and reverting apache2.conf doesn't help. I tried to restart the apache server, but it does not help.

Please, tell me why this happens and how can i bring everything back?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve the issue, but restoring previous backup of the www helped. Maybe something happened with .htaccess, because sometimes it becomes invisible or smth.